# Choices.js: Add dynamic data into the select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm using [Choices.js](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices) for multi select and for a select with a search box. I am also using angular.js to populate the data but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody help me with populating the options dynamically.

The data is being retrieved using Ajax.

This is what I've tried

```
<label for="docno" class="col-form-label">Name :</label>
<select id='docno' class="choices form-select" ng-model="docno" ng-change='getDocs()' required="true">
     <option ng-repeat="d in documents" ng-value="d.docno" selected='selected'>{{d.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setValue in choices instance like below :

```js
var choices = new Choices(document.getGetElementById("docno"));
var myDynamicItems = [
    {
        value: 'Value 1',
        label: 'Label 1',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        value: 'Value 2',
        label: 'Label 2',
        id: 2
    }
];

inst.choices.setValue(myDynamicItems);
```

Comment: unfortunately my page was much more complicated that it was not possible to use choices.setValue(), I ended up using [Select2](https://select2.org/) and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

if you use default single select from choices.js, just remove `data-trigger` attribute and it should work fine.

as on choices.js demo source code [here](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices/blob/5dbea2825a5887d88d6947443f4874bb7b84cc3a/public/index.html#L321-L330) | [Demo Link](https://choices-js.github.io/Choices/)